are my ss benefits taxable income if my spouse continues working?
I can't get a straight answer on this as none of the calculators on line make a distinction between my salary  and my spouses salary, my ss benefit vs spousal benefits, etc.   My situation is this:

married filing jointly
I'm turning 62, I won't be working, but my ss benefit is some $30,000 a year. I plan on not having any earned income for 2025, just the ss benefit and withdrawals from 401k/IRA's.  The ss benefit is NOT spousal benefits, this is my earned SS benefit.
my spouse wants to continue working for 4 more years, making around $100,000 a year.

the question is, are my ss benefits taxable income?   not counting taking money out of 401k/IRA, our agi will be the $130,000 (I know the standard deduction but lets forget about that for now,) but MY PERSONAL income is $0.   can anybody tell me what I can expect in taxes or how to lessen my tax burden?   References would also be great if possible.

in the tax law is says that "up to 85%" of the SS benefit is taxable if MFJ income is greater than 44k. Why do they say "up to 85%" instead of just "85%", it implies you can make more than $44k, and be able to lower the tax on ss to less than 85%, I want to know how you do that.

The actual amount of benefits which are taxable (0%-85%) is found by completing "Social Security Benefits Worksheet" in the instructions for form 1040 for lines 6a and 6b.  Without going through the full form, at 130k gross for MFJ, you'll be at the high end of the range, unless you have unusually high schedule 1 income adjustments.

"I can't get a straight answer on this as none of the calculators on line make a distinction between my salary and my spouses salary" -- I suspect that's because if you're married filing jointly there isn't a distinction

You should take a look at the SSA page on this. Specifically:

File a joint return, and you and your spouse have a combined income* that is

Between $32,000 and $44,000, you may have to pay income tax on up to 50% of your benefits.
More than $44,000, up to 85% of your benefits may be taxable.


Given that your total AGI on your joint return is expected to be way above the $44K limit, you should expect up to 85% of your benefits to be taxable. It doesn't matter how you attribute the total income between the two of you.

yeah, I read that.  It's the the "up to " part that has me asking the question. I read somewhere before I came here that you can separate your incomes, still file jointly, and reduce that 85% number, but It was only one article, and I can't find any supporting document.

the short is, why do they say "up to 85%" instead of just "85%", it implies you can make more than $44k, and be able to lower the tax on ss to less than 85%, I want to know how you do that.

The IRS has a calculator here: https://www.irs.gov/help/ita/are-my-social-security-or-railroad-retirement-tier-i-benefits-taxable

yes that is where I started,  not this year as I haven't gotten their yet, but hey had an estimator for the taxes but it didn't do a good job of separating my and my spouse

@JonathanLeslie It says "Up to" because it is a sliding scale of inclusion; earning $1 above the threshold doesn't make 85% of your benefits taxable; as your combined AGI goes up, the taxable amount goes up as well, up to the cap of 85%.

You are going to pay some tax based on the chart everyone has commented on if you file a joint return. So, do a test.  What would happen if you two filed separate returns.  You can file separate returns, no IRS issue with that.
